# Is there a good way to do cache saves in goroutine?

Tags: go

Let's say I have a `handler` that makes a request and gets the latest data on the selected stock:

```
func (ss *stockService) GetStockInfo(ctx *gin.Context) {
    code := ctx.Param("symbol")

    ss.logger.Info("code", code)
    url := fmt.Sprintf("URL/%v", code)
    ss.logger.Info(url)
    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        errs.HTTPErrorResponse(ctx, &ss.logger, errs.New(errs.Internal, err))
        return
    }
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        errs.HTTPErrorResponse(ctx, &ss.logger, errs.New(errs.Internal, err))
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    var chart ChartResponse
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&chart)

    if err != nil {
        errs.HTTPErrorResponse(ctx, &ss.logger, errs.New(errs.Internal, err))
        return
    }
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, chart)

}
```

And I want to add caching here. Since I don't have a lot of experience right now, I'm interested in proper interaction with the cache.

I think that if, for example, it is not possible to save to the cache for some reason, then you can simply make a request to the api. Then I wonder if it would be right to save to the cache in a separate goroutine and immediately return the response:

```
func (ss *stockService) GetStockInfo(ctx *gin.Context) {
    code := ctx.Param("symbol")
    stockInfo, err := ss.cache.Get(code)
    if err == nil {
        // FIND 
        ...
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, chart)

    } else {
        ss.logger.Info("code", code)
        url := fmt.Sprintf("URL/%v", code)
        ss.logger.Info(url)
        req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, url, nil)
        ...
        err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&chart)
        // IS IT A GOOD WAY ?
        go ss.cache.Save(code,chart,expireAt)
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, chart)
    }

}
```

I use redis as a cache.

I will be glad if someone says what is wrong with this approach.

Comment: If this is an in-memory cache with fast access, then you don't need to start a new goroutine. If this cache is something like a db table and you want to save API response there, then you might want to consider running it in a goroutine. I suggest you simply call the cache, and deal with the details there.